# e.pageX return undefined when mousewheel event on FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel, mouse-position

I am trying to get mouse position when mousewheel event.

Here is fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/7/

```
$("#container").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.pageX);
  console.log(e);
}
);
```

It shows undefined.
What's wrong with this implementation?

Comment: The fiddle looks good, working ok in latest chrome...

Comment: Sorry, try on firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try accessing `e.originalEvent.pageX` instead, that will access the vanilla JS event that looks like working ok in firefox too.

Looks like this is just a jquery v2 bug. After updating jquery version to jquery 3 in your fiddle it works with `e.pageX` too.

https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/8/

Comment: Thanks, but most of the answers on stackoverflow say to use e.pageX and until now I used e.pageX.

Comment: Well it looks like its just a jquery bug. After updating jquery version to jquery 3 it works with `e.pageX` too.